# How do I group pod metrics by deployment in Prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Prometheus has metrics such as `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`. However, they are only grouped by pod. How can I group them by deployment/cronjobs/etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to handle this with the following query:

`((label_replace((rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[2m]) * on(pod) group_left(owner_name) (sum without (instance) (kube_pod_owner))), "replicaset", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)")) * on(replicaset) group_left(owner_name) (sum without (instance) (kube_replicaset_owner{})))`

Here is the explanation:

- Join `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` with `kube_pod_owner` on `pod`
- Copy over the `owner_name` from `kube_pod_owner`
- Use `label_replace` to rename `kube_pod_owner`'s `owner_name` to `replicaset`
- Join that with kube_replicaset_owner on `replicaset`
- Copy over the `owner_name` from `kube_replicaset_owner` (this value is your deployment etc)

The `without (instance)` are used to remove the `instance` field from the joined sets. Because there can be multiple instances for a single deployment, this can cause issues.

Lastly, the `rate` function is called on `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` directly at the innermost area because otherwise Prometheus complains about `parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors`. Placing it in the innermost area is a workaround.

Comment: A useful answer, thank you. I'm going to learn from this too.