# PromQL: reuse group label in another metric

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I have multiple pods controlled by a workflow. To retrieve the controlling workflow name I have the following query:
`group by(owner_name)(kube_pod_owner{owner_kind="Workflow"})`.

Now I want to reuse the `owner_name` field to measure the CPU usage of the pods controlled by the grouped workflows.
For this I think about something like this: `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"${owner_name}-.*"}`.

How do I combine those two statements? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: [How do I group pod metrics by deployment in Prometheus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571975/how-do-i-group-pod-metrics-by-deployment-in-prometheus)
Try something like this:

```
(
    sum by (pod) (label_replace(
        (
            rate(
                container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[2m]) * on(pod) group_left(owner_name) 
                (sum without (instance) (kube_pod_owner{owner_kind="Workflow"}))
            ), 
            "pod", "$1", "owner_name", "(.*)"
        )
    )
)
```